# Maven src/main/resources not filtering

Tags: maven, filtering, war

When I do jetty:run...the resulting war filters correctly.
When I do package...the resulting war does NOT filter correctly.
What am I doing wrong?

```
  <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <finalName>MyWarName</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.source}</source>
                <target>${jdk.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <contextXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-context.xml</contextXml>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Why u r including and then excluding same resources?

Comment: I'm not the first block includes filtered resources and the second includes not filtered resources.

Comment: To simplify you could remove the second block and see if it helps. Is it doing anything for you here? It reads to me like: first block is including files for filtering; second block is excluding files from not being filtered

Comment: And if you're trying to exclude files from your war you can use the maven-war-plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the properties that are not being replaced:

System properties

Project properties:

```
<project>
...
<properties>
    <the_name>value</value>
</properties>
...
</project>
```

Filters on build with .properties file:

```
<project>
...
<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>the_values.properties</filter>
    </filters>
</build>
...
</project>
```